# plotting n number of equal points in circular direction in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

I am working on the task in which I have to make a circle which is having n number of equal parts. I am provided with centre and radius of the circle which is (0,0) and 4 respectively. To achieve this task, I have written below code,

```
parts = 36                     # desire number of parts of the circle          
theta_zero = 360/parts
R = 4                          # Radius

x_p = []
y_p = []

n = 0
for n in range(0,36):
    x_p.append(R * math.cos(n*theta_zero))
    y_p.append(R * math.sin(n*theta_zero))
```

However, after running this code, I got output like below which does not seem a coorect which I am suppose to have.

[image]

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong and give some suggestion of correct code. Thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure `math.cos` and `math.sin` take values in radians and not in degrees.

Comment: Also, plt.axis('equal')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you are generating numbers in degrees and passing them to a function that expects radians, there's a much simpler and less error-prone method for generating evenly-spaced coordinates:

```
t0 = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, parts, endpoint=False)
x0 = R * np.cos(t0)
y0 = R * np.sin(t0)
```

`endpoint=False` ensures that you end up with 36 partitions rather than 35, since otherwise `0` and `2 * np.pi` would overlap.

If you wanted to connect the dots for your circle, you would want the overlap. In that case, you would do

```
t1 = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, parts + 1)
x1 = R * np.cos(t1)
y1 = R * np.sin(t1)
```

Here is how you would plot a circle with the 36 sectors delineated:

```
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(np.stack((np.zeros(parts), x0), 0),
         np.stack((np.zeros(parts), y0), 0))
```

Finally, if you want your circle to look like a circle, you may want to run `plt.axis('equal')` after plotting.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative way of doing my mentioned task. When I plotted x and y coordinates using your code. I got a plot of a circle which shows a line (probably connecting every nodes in the circle) from 0 degree to 350 degree, but, itdoes not show a line between the angle 350 degree and 360 degree.  I hope you got my point correctly. 

The second question I have to ask you that, the circle which formed after plotting, does contain the 36 equal parts?

It would be very nice of you if you clear these doubts. Thank you once again for your detailed answer.

Comment: @Urvesh. I showed you the second version if you want to draw lines. The first version is only for 36 dots. You need 37 dots if you want to connect them and have the ends overlap.

Comment: @Urvesh If it wasn't clear, you have to recompute x and y when you change t.

Comment: @Urvesh. Let me know if you're still having issues

Comment: Okay, I got your point. If I write 't5 = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, parts + 1)', then I got all dots connected to each other. But yes, it is the case that 0 and 2 * np.pi might be overlapped to eachother. Because If I do not write endpoint = False and instead I write parts + 1 then I got one extra point.

Comment: @Urvesh. Exactly. When you plot lines, matplotlib will never automatically connect the endpoints for you. That means that you need to manually add an overlapping extra point if you want a closed shape.

Comment: But I would like to clear one thing that, does this connected circle (with line) have 36 equal parts? 

The reason behind this question is, I want to project the nodes of an geometry which will be inside the circle. Therefore If I do project the nodes to the circle, I have to make sure that in which interval my projection line intersect to the circle.

Comment: @Urvesh. Yes, the second option generates 37 points with two overlaps, which means that you get 36 sectors. If you need the coordinates of the sector boundaries, use the first option.

Comment: Okay, Understood. Thank you so much for your detailed explaination. I really appreciate your help. If I have any issue further I will leave a comment here.

Comment: @Urvesh. See the update. I showed how to use the two options to plot a circle and the sectors

Comment: Ohkay, I used the updated code which you provided and now I got the plot which shows fully connected circle with divided parts.  Thank you so very much for this.

Comment: Hello, would you please see my latest question here and would you please give me a guidance on it?

Answer (score 1):

Your circle is weird because `math.cos` and `math.sin` accept radians while you are passing degrees. You just need to convert the degrees to radians when calling the math functions.

Like this:

```py
parts = 36         
theta_zero = 360/parts
R = 4 

x_p = []
y_p = []

for n in range(0,36):
    x_p.append(R * math.cos(n*theta_zero /180*math.pi))
    y_p.append(R * math.sin(n*theta_zero /180*math.pi))
```

Result:

[image: Circle]

Alternatively changing `theta_zero` to `2*math.pi/parts` would also work and would be slightly faster but it might be a little less intuitive to work with.

Also as @Mad Physicist mentioned you should probably add `plt.axis('equal')` to unstretch the image.

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me. and I got the plot which I wanted. I also include plt.axis('equal').  This code works well for me. I appriciate yor help.